# Comparing sum against the average of all sums

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I am looking for a way to compare the payroll of a team compared to the average of other teams in the same league.  Here is the table structure, three standard tables and two connecting tables to address my many to many relationships.  Using PostgreSQL.

```
tblPlayer
PNAME    PSALARY
player1  100000
player2  110000
player3  200000
player4  300000
player5  210000
player6  120000
```

contblPlayerTable

```
ID       PNAME       TNAME
1        player1     teamA
2        player2     teamA
3        player3     teamA
4        player4     teamB
5        player5     teamB
7        player6     teamC
```

tblTeam

```
TNAME    
teamA
teamB
teamC
```

contblTeamLeague

```
ID       TNAME       LNAME
1        teamA       leagueA
2        teamB       leagueA
3        teamC       leagueB
```

tblLeague

```
LNAME
leagueA
leagueB
```

---

I need to calculate each teams payroll that belong to leagueA so that we can determine the average total team payroll for leagueA

I also need to calculate the difference for teamA's payroll compared to the leagueA average.

Final output should be a $amount that is (teamA payroll (410,000) - leagueA average (410,000+630,000)/2=520,000) = -110,000

This shows that teamA has a total payroll that is 110,000 below the leagueA average.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Please change your table (for all tables) information to DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo...`) and your data to DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...`) - this will help greatly those who wish to assist with your problem. You could also use a fiddle (copy the data here also) - TIA. p.s.welcome to the forum!

Comment: Understand, thank you for the correction.  First post...

Comment: Any sign of the changes I asked for? You can notify me by commenting and putting `@Vérace` in the message!